# How to add unit and Integration test classes for a controller class in same package

Tags: unit-testing, grails, integration-testing, spring-tool-suite

I have a project in which I have to add Unit Test classes and Integration Test Classes for a Controller class.

I have all Domain Controller and Unit Integration classes under same package.
I am using GGTS (Groovy and Grails Tools Suit)
It throws an error to (Unit and Integration) test class saying "Test Class already defined"

I am new to adding Unit test and Integration test together.
Can you please help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rename one of them to include the test type, e.g. if I create the unit test first then I name the integration test FooControllerIntegrationTests.